# absoluteness and and transitivity

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm early in my reading about absoluteness, but one thing has me stuck, so I thought I'd ask.  One reason absoluteness seems to matter is that we feel confident that we know what we're talking about when we ascribe properties that are absolute.  But the structures considered are almost always transitive (and often also models of ZF).  Can't one find a non-transitive model which "thinks of itself" as transitive?  If so, then why think that because a property is absolute in transitive models that we have a better grip on it?  Aren't we "cheating"?

Comment: As far as I understand, transitivity can't be expressed in the model. Or, put it differently, the model always thinks it is transitive: $x\in y \in V\implies x\in V$, because the consequent is trivially true.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro.  That's helpful, but does it solve the problem?  The problem is: how do we know that we are in a transitive universe?  And, if we don't, then why should learning that a property is absolute for transitive models assure us that we know what we mean when ascribing them?

Comment: Absoluteness is a relation between *pairs* of models and formulas. It makes no sense to discuss it with only one model around. If we say that $\phi$ is absolute for $M$, what we mean is that $\phi$ is absolute between $V$ and $M$. If you have a property that is absolute between transitive models, and a model that is not transitive, there is no reason to expect that the property would be absolute between $V$ and the model. For instance, consider $V$, a model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\lnot{\rm Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and $\phi\equiv{\rm Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

Comment: Thanks, Andres.  That's very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

What does it mean for a model to "think of itself transitive"? It means that whenever $x$ is in the model, and the model thinks that $y\in x$, then $y$ is in the model.

But in order for the model to even know about $y$ it had to be in the model to begin with. So every model thinks it is transitive.

Now take a countable elementary submodel of any large enough portion of the universe, e.g. $H(\omega_2)$, in which $\omega_1$ is definable, and show that your submodel cannot be transitive.